# WARNING: psql major version 9.3, server major version 9.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run psql commands to import data into Redshift as specified here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html. Our application is hosted on Heroku. I had a script and it was working perfectly fine, uploading the data without an error.

Then we added a PostgreSQL database under the same app but for a different section of the code. It was version 9.4. Ever since then, I have not been able to import into our Redshift table using the exact same script. This is the error that I see:

```
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package.
```

Interestingly, I am able to connect to the psql client on Heroku by running `heroku pg:psql -a myapp`. I do, however, get this warning message when psql first starts:

```
---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
psql (9.3.4, server 9.4.4)
WARNING: psql major version 9.3, server major version 9.4.
         Some psql features might not work.
```

Is this an error with the psql client or with Heroku? Do I need to upgrade psql to 9.4, and if so, how do I do that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Heroku runs on 9.4 (server). Your `psql` client is older: you'll need to install the latest version, although the differences between 9.3 and 9.4 are minor on the psql front.

Comment: do you know how I do that on Heroku? it doesn't seem like there is a way

Comment: psql is on YOUR machine. Update that.

Answer (score 1):

The message says your client and DB server version. You are connecting to you new DB server instead of Redshift. The psql output has to be similar to the following:psql (9.3.9, server 8.0.2) as Redshift postgres version is too old.